# Use L'Hospital's rule to prove a certain limit

Tags: limits, derivatives

> Assume that $f''(x)$ is continuous and prove that 
>   $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h) -2f(x)+ f(x-h)}{h^2} = f''(x).$$

How  should I differentiate the $-2f(x)$ part? since the derivative corresponding to $h$ and there is no $h$ there.

From what I know, the second derivative of LHS should be :
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f''(x+h)+ ?? + f''(x-h)}{2} = f''(x)$$ and by plug-in $h$ and $??=0$ it would match the RHS.

Is that mean derivative of $-2f(x)$ is zero in this case?

Comment: $\dfrac{df(x)}{dh}=0$.

Comment: Would you have doubts if in the limit you take $x=2$ (or whatever point where $f$ is defined) just to work out a specific case?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $f(x)$ is just a constant with respect to $h$.

But shouldn't it be $h^2$ instead of $2h$ in the denominator of the original limit?

Comment: thanks, that's clear things up !